# Authenticate the caller to a lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a web app.
The login process is done  with cognito (AWS javascript SDK) in the client side.
This works fine. The user can register, login and edit his attributes in cognito.

I have a Lambda function. 
The Lambda function is triggered via an API gateway.

The question:
What is the best practice for authenticating the calling user in Lambda?

What do I need to pass in my HTTP request? Is it the accessToken from the client?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the access token in headers.

Comment: is there a specific header that Lambda expects? Can you point me to the relevant documentation? Thanks @AtulSharma

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-flow

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html

Comment: Do you want to create a cognito authorization via api gateway?

Comment: @AtulSharma about the autherizer - what is the key that I need to pass to the API gateway? Is it the accessToken from the client?

Comment: @AssaelAzran yes and no :). This question is about API gateway, but more generally I wonder how to authenticate the user in my own server? Like an Apache server running in my own server..

Comment: @carmel you can use JWT to authorize your users. you need to authorize your users and not authenticate. They have been already authenticated via cognito.If you want i can show you step by step how to authorize your users via api gateway using cognito accessToken

Comment: @AssaelAzran Didn't think about the fact that I don't need to authenticate the user. I'll look into it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You pass that in the header 
Authorization: Bearer {yourtoken}

{yourtoken} is the idToken in AuthenticationResult when you request CognitoIdentityServiceProvider

If you want the caller in your lambda function you can pass it to your lambda function with $context.authorizer.claims.email in API Gateway request template

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this option